# Question on the complexity of Boruvka's algorithm, implemented with a Union-Find structure

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have implemented Boruvka's algorithm with a union-find structure to keep track of the components:

```
method boruvkas(GraphEdgeList, numOfNodes):
    compCount = numOfNodes
    cheapest = Array(numOfNodes), initialized with (0, 0, ∞)
    MSTEdgeList = []
    while compCount > 1:
        for (u, v, w) in GraphEdgeList:
            comp1 = find(u), comp2 = find(v)
            if comp1 != comp2:
                if w < cheapest[comp1]:
                    cheapest[comp1] = (u, v, w)
                if w < cheapest[comp2]:
                    cheapest[comp2] = (u, v, w)
        for i from 1 to nNodes:
            e = cheapest[i]
            if e.weight != ∞:
                comp1 = find(e.first), comp2 = find(e.second)
                if comp1 != comp2:
                    unite(comp1, comp2)
                    MSTEdgeList.add(e)
                    compCount--
        reset(cheapest, (0, 0, ∞))
    return MSTEdgeList
```

I understand that the outer loop runs log(V) times, as the number of components approximately halves in each iteration. The first for loop runs E times, but each time the `find` operation takes log(V) time. The second loop however, runs as many times as the number of components. I have read that the complexity of Boruvka's algorithm is Elog(V), but I can't really see why.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured something out. The 1st for loop runs E times, with `find` operation each time, so it is ***O(Elog(V))***, the second for runs ***log(V)*** times (as many components there are in each iteration), and the `find` and `unite` operations take log(V). So it runs with ***O(logV*logV)***. The while loop also runs log(V) times, so the overall complexity must be ***O(Elog^2V+log^3(V))=O((E+logV)log^2V)=O(Elog^2(V))***.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in assuming that all those union and find operations take O(log V) time.  They don't.  They don't even take the usual (n) time.

In the first sub-loop, a find operation is performed on every vertex adjacent to an edge.  Each find takes O(1) time, plus some time to traverse internal links.  Each internal link is destroyed when it is traversed, however, and there are at most O(E) such links, so all together, the first sub-loop takes O(E) time.  All the runs of the first loop together therefor take O(E log V).

The second sub-loop can be made faster by only iterating over roots with new edges.  Then we have to consider that the total number of union and find operations performed by all runs of the second sub-loop is O(min(V,E)). All runs together therefore take O(min(V,E)(min(V,E))).  That's smaller than the O(E log V), that the first loop uses, so the total time is O(E log V).

Comment: I don't understand why the union and find operations are constant time. As the disjoint sets grow in cardinality, than there are much more links between each element of a set to the representative of that set.

Comment: The path compression performed during find() links each element directly to its set representative.

Comment: Well my implementation of Union-Find doesn't do that unfortunately, because I used the one in the Competitive Programmer's Handbook. In that implementation there is no path compression, but I see how it can be done. Also, in the second part of your response, why did you mention O(min(V,E)). Why do we take the minimum between edges and vertices?

Comment: Well, that explains it. You need a better union-find implementation.  min(V,E) is important when you have, say, a lot of disconnected vertices and only a few edges, or when you have a dense graph with around V(V-1)/2 edges.